# which is the right way of parsing json response using GSON? Json parsing twice or creating response class everytime?

Tags: android, json, parsing, gson, memory-efficient

I want to know in a scenario where server json response is in the below format

```
{
 "data": {
    "id": 1948,
    "body": "test comment",
    "created_at": "2014-06-24T16:05:31+00:00",
    "user_id": 2963,
    ...
}
}
```

in Json parsing using GSON, whether it is right to parse

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
String jsonData = jsonObject.getString("data");
return Response.success(mGson.fromJson(json,mClazz),HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
```

or to just return

Response.success(mGson.fromJson(json,mClazz),HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
and create a response class for every server api call like

```
public class CommentsResponse {  
 private Comment data;
 ..
}
```

Comment: you can easily check that yourself. what you tried?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Can You please suggest which is better in the two scenarios and why

Answer (score 0):

The first case might be better because it tells if you if the response was a valid JSONObject or not when you convert the reponse to JSONObject and you might wanna handle that case since an exception will be thrown if its not.